# Resource file referenced in resx not found on windows 2012

Tags: c#, embedded-resource, windows-server-2012, class-library

I have a class library `dll` with an file embedded as a resource that is referenced in `Resources.resx`.

```
    internal class Resources {
        internal static byte[] LicenseFile {
            get {
                object obj = ResourceManager.GetObject("LicenseFile", resourceCulture);
                return ((byte[])(obj));
            }
        }
    }
```

This library is referenced by multiple applications such as a windows service.

This works without problems on local windows 7 machine or older windows server 2008.

But the service does not starts in windows server 2012 since it does not finds the file.

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException` is thrown as the system event log shows.

**Update**

I printed out stacktrace and it seems it cannot find the required dll. Its not the resource file at all.

*Could not load file or assembly 'LeadTools.dll' or one of its dependencies. Module not found.*

```
Dateiname: 'Leadtools.dll'
   at MyClassLibrary.Utils.InitLeadTools()
   at MyService.Logic.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Is the space following the string "LicenseFile" supposed to be in there?

Comment: Its just an example String. As stated it works on local windows 7 and server 2008. I want to deploy service to server 2012 with same dll.

Comment: What, exactly, is an `IOFileException`? Can you maybe provide, I dunno, a full stack trace to help us help you?

Comment: Sounds like a problem with pulling a resource from satellite dll..

Comment: @IanKemp Has an excellent point: `IOFileException` is not a standard exception; it's a class specific to your application. Which also means that your application is likely throwing it.

Comment: Try-catch that code for IOFileException. Get us a stack trace, and if present, the InnerException. Until that happens, you're unlikely to see much movement on this question.

Comment: Misstyped IOFileException, it is `System.IO.FileNotFoundException`  @Lynn Crumbling will do.

Comment: Is it possible that the embedded DLL doesn't match the bitness of the machine that is experiencing the problem?

Comment: I found in LeadTools forum that i needed to install `Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x64)` on the server 2012. Not it works.  Sorry for wasting your time and thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice! Glad to hear you've got a solution :)

Comment: @LynnCrumbling Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LEADTOOLS binaries for .NET 4.0 require redistributing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 runtime files.

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

Comment: This is correct. The LEADTOOLS v19 help topic "Files To Be Included With Your Application" states that "LEADTOOLS binaries for .NET 2.0-3.5 require redistributing Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 runtime files." and "LEADTOOLS binaries for .NET 4.0 require redistributing Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 runtime files."